# $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. How can we show this inequality?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

How can we show ?

$$\left(\frac{2a}{b+c}\right)^{2/3}+\left(\frac{2b}{c+a}\right)^{2/3}+\left(\frac{2c}{a+b}\right)^{2/3}\geq 3$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: No constraint on a,b,c ?

Comment: There is a nice proof by AM-GM.

Comment: Also by AM-GM we have $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{2a}{b+c}\right)^{\frac{27}{46}}\geq3$